# What Collation is the best for data type INT in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, types

When a filed is INT(data type), what should I choose as collation in MySQL?

Comment: pardon me if I'm being naive, but isn't collation only for character data (to determine the set of rules used to sort characters)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Collation affects *string* sorting. It doesn't have any effect on numeric data types.

It may, howevever, have an effect on how numbers embedded in strings are sorted. But that's still no effect on numeric data types such as INT.

Comment: you are right -- just to add: if you deal with multi-lang pages and have list to sort in e.g. Polish and you have to force proper collation for sorting, and :) you use e.g. INT column as sorting vector, then you better have collation set (e.g. to UTF8), or you will get SQL errors, e.g.: "Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_polish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'"

Comment: You can force the collation on a field by field case in the SELECT "after" the comparison: SELECT [...] WHERE last_name = 'Saldana' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AND age = 37;  If you add the COLLATE just at the end of that sentence, the collation would apply to the age field and so trigger that (strange) error about 'latin1'. Try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/491fd5/5

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you can specify a collation (or a character set for that matter) only for string types, ie. the types VARCHAR, CHAR, ENUM, SET, and TEXT types (TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT)